# My iPhone won't pair to my August EP650R headphones

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I have had my headphones paired to my iPhone but needed to disconnect recently which wouldn't work so I had to 'forget the device'. Now my iPhone won't pair with my headphones at all. Is there a way to get them paired again?

Comment: do you know how to set the Augustus headphone in to discovery mode , so your iPhone can find it ?

Comment: The first thing to do is isolate the problem - is it with your iPhone or your headset.  Do this by trying to connect the headset to a different device (another phone, a PC, a Mac, etc.)  If it works on a different device, then chances are, it's your iPhone.  Start with that and post the results.

Comment: You will find the instructions here https://www.augustint.com/download/manuals/EP636_EN.pdf

Comment: Thanks Allan. Headphones won't pair with my iPad but paired straight away on another iPhone. Confused.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding you correctly, it won't pair with your iPhone or iPad but it *will* pair with a completely *different* iPhone?  Try deleting the pairing from both your iOS devices and pair again as if new.  The manual also has a procedure to do a factory reset of your headset.  Try that as well.

Comment: Thanks Allan. I used the manual and my 10 year old helped me to put the headphones into discover mode again  Contacted Apple support and between you all you've helped me get my headphones and iPhone connecting again! Thank you so much for your help, it's much appreciated 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to settings -> Bluetooth and make sure the switch is turned on:

[image: on]

Then make sure the headphones are in a range of up to 10 metres and in a state to be paired to the phone.

If this doesn’t work try:

- Turning Bluetooth on and off on both the phone and the device
- Resetting the device and restarting the phone
- Contacting the device manufacturer

Comment: Thanks! I've tried switching Bluetooth and phone off and on. I am having trouble resetting my headphones after following the manufacturers instructions, it doesn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Thank you for your help. My 10 year old helped me put my headphones into discover more, obviously I wasn't doing it properly  Very pleased, thankful for all the support...

Answer (score 0):

try resetting network settings first if you are reluctant to reset whole phone at once. It is settings-> general-> reset-> network reset.

also to rule out the obvious, try pairing headphones and phone both to a third working device which can be a laptop or some other speakers.

Comment: Thanks. It will pair with another iPhone so I guess it's my phone at fault. Do you know if I reset the network settings will my iPhone forget the other devices it's already paired with?

Comment: I don’t really know sorry! Try a simple reboot most often it works. If I have to guess, i’ll say no. It won’t forget them all. Coz I myself have done it a few times and things were there as they were. Try apple support to check for a similar question about network reset

Comment: Thank you!! I contacted apple support and then my 10 year old came along will I was chatting to them and helped his momma put the headphones into discover mode again!! I'm so pleased!! 